# how to get notified when a certain Application is started?

Tags: blackberry

hie,
i want to listen when a certain application after listening i want to show a dialog first over there,
how it is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to get a notification, but if you have an app running, you could poll for the list of running apps using `net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationManager.getVisibleApplications()` - call that, say, every few seconds and check when the app you're looking for shows up in the list.

Comment: thanks a lot.
but for this i have to use a timer running in background.
which takes a lot of battery,
can there is no other way we get notified or any kind of observer here in blackberry ?
plz help me?

Comment: I think it shouldn't be too bad if you do a Thread.sleep call, and sleep for a few seconds each time.